# Is it possible to attach three external monitors to two outputs?

Tags: multiple-monitors, vga

I have two monitors connected to my laptop which has two outputs (VGA to HDMI and VGA to USB-C).

I now have a third monitor and wonder if it might be possible to attach it by somehow expanding an existing input to allow for two monitors to be connected as two independent devices.

Another thought I had would be to split the other USB-C socket (which is used for charging) into two so that it can both charge and receive an input simultaneously.

Are either of these scenarios possible?

Is there something else that could work?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, this is possible! By splitting the signal of your port, you can use several monitors at the same time through one port. Both of these scenarios would work.

EDIT: Here are a few references. [Dell](https://www.dell.com/community/Laptops-General-Read-Only/HDMI-to-2-dual-monitors/td-p/4314146), [The Technology Land](https://thetechnologyland.com/guide-on-how-to-setup-dual-monitors-with-hdmi-splitter/), and [HelpMeRick.com](https://helpmerick.com/split-your-video-signal-onto-two-monitors.htm)

Comment: Great! Do you have a reference for this?

Comment: @SnookerFan if an anecdote helps, I used to do it all the time - I did desktop support at a small place a few years back and we had numerous three-monitor setups that were all done via one HDMI-in to one monitor and one DVI-in split to two monitors.

Comment: @SnookerFan Edited answer to contain references